# Why can't I assign a double the same literal value of Double.Min and Max?

Tags: c#, double, literals

Decompiling the source and looking up `Double.Min` and `Double.Max` shows the following definition:

```
public const double MinValue = -1.79769313486232E+308;
public const double MaxValue = 1.79769313486232E+308;
```

This matches up with the [msdn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.minvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2).

If I try to assign this maximal value manually to a variable I get the following error:

```
Floating-point constant is outside the range of type 'double'
```

```
double d1 = -1.79769313486232E+308; // DOESN'T COMPILE
Double d2 = 1.79769313486232E+308; // DOESN'T COMPILE
```

Can someone explain to me why this is? Is there something wrong with the double boundary validation?

Comment: 1.79769313486232E+308 is rounded up a little, maybe that's why? The max value would be 1.79769313486231570814..E+308

Comment: Yeah, I think you've got incorrect values. Type `double.MaxValue`, click it an hit F12 to go to the definition. Copy that value (`1.7976931348623157E+308`) and assign it. Compiles right for me: `double d = 1.7976931348623157E+308;`.

Comment: @harold `double.Parse("1.79769313486231E+308")` crashes, too. I saw a few double parsing bugs on GitHub recently. I believe parsing the max value was among them.

Comment: VS says it is minus infinity : double MinValue = 10 * (-.179769313486232E+308D);
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is a known .NET Framework and .NET Core bug.](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13615) Since the Roslyn compiler likely just uses the .NET Framework parsing code the compiler invalidly rejects this double value.

harold has pointed out that the value is rounded. But if you round it down then it still does not work.

```
double.Parse("1.79769313486231E+308")
```

throws an `OverflowException`.

This GitHub issue links to many other floating point parsing bugs. It was surprising to me to see how broken this fundamental framework feature is.

Comment: It was my understanding that Roslyn implemented its own double-parsing routine, here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/fab7134296816fc80019c60b0f5bef7400cf23ea/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/RealParser.cs#L31 though whether it shares logic with an underlying .NET Core library I do not know. I never worked on this part of the lexer.  Regardless, I share your surprise; parsing the max double is an obvious test case and this should have been found by the developer on the day the code was first written!

Comment: I am particularly surprised since floating point parsing issues have a long history, and developers of compilers should not be naive about them. Back in the 1990s when I was on the JScript team we implemented our own float parsing library because the default ones were too buggy to handle all of the cases we needed to make a compliant ECMAScript implementation. You'd think that would have improved by now.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the linked (and closed) issue is about string parsing. The OP is doing direct assignment and gunr2171's comment is correct, OP used the wrong value...